# Bootstrap 5 class "col-md-4 " is not working

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-5

I want to make a grid of 3 columns and 2 rows using Bootstrap cards but the Grid is not working. All the cards are centered and one after the other. Please help me resolve this.

**Service.jsx**

```
const Service =() =>{
    return(
      <div>
        <div className="my-5">
          <h1 className="text-center">Our Services</h1>
        </div>
        <div className="container-fluid mb-5">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="col-10 mx-auto">
              <div className="row gy-3">
                {Sdata.map((val, ind) => {
                    return(
                      <Card key={ind} imgsrc={val.imgsrc} title={val.title} />
                    )})}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
```

**Card.jsx**

```
const Card =(props) =>{
    return(
      <div>
            <div className="col-md-4 col-10 mx-auto">
                <div className="card">
                    <img src={props.imgsrc} className="card-img-top" alt={props.imgsrc} />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title font-weight-bold">{props.title}</h5>
                            <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <NavLink to="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</NavLink>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    );
  };
```

Comment: For Bootstrap 5 you just need to use `col-5`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> "All the cards are centered and one after the other".

The columns are being wrapped by an outer `div`. Columns must be directly in the parent `.row`. Remove the outer div.

```
const Card =(props) =>{
    return(
            <div className="col-md-4 col-10 mx-auto">
                <div className="card">
                    <img src={props.imgsrc} className="card-img-top" alt={props.imgsrc} />
                        <div className="card-body">
                            <h5 className="card-title font-weight-bold">{props.title}</h5>
                            <p className="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <NavLink to="#" className="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</NavLink>
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    );
  };
```

[React demo on Codeply](https://codeply.com/p/4HzbvDFSue)